# Initializing all the structure variable at once

Tags: c++

```
struct LoadsForAPDLScript
{
    double JntLCLoad;
    double JntPPLoad;
    double JntLimManLoad;
    double JntLimShockLoad;
    double JntOthLimTenLoad;
    double JntOthLimManLoad;
    double JntBPLoad;
    double JntUltManLoad;
    double JntUltShockLoad;
    double JntOthUltTenLoad;
    double JntOthUltManLoad;
};
```

Is there any way to initialize all the struct variable mentioned above in one line instead of initializing it one by one  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's C++, an empty constructor will automatically initialize all member variables of simple numerical types with zero.

```
struct LoadsForAPDLScript {
    ...
    LoadsForAPDLScript() {}
};
```

With C compatibility in mind, I'm not quite sure about whether an implicit default constructor will do this as well. Perhaps somebody has the C++ standard at hand (or knows it by heart), then please extend this answer.

Comment: Everything depends if struct is managed by author of the question or is it included from 3rd party libraries. By everything I mean possibility to add constructor to this struct ;)

Comment: The best library header cannot withstand clever abuse of the preprocessor. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use `memset`:

```
LoadsForADPLScript instance;
memset(&instance, 0, sizeof(LoadsForADPScript));
```

Comment: This will only work if ALL your members are POD (which they are in this case).

Comment: How can you initialize all the structure members with some user defined value ?like here i want to initialize starting from JntLCLoad  to JntOthUltManLoad to some values lets say 88 .How to do that ?